# Postgres: Ordering result by to_char date field

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT SUM(round("records"."value")) AS sum_value, 
    to_char(service_date_time, 'Mon YYYY') AS to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
FROM "records" 
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "records"."category_id" 
WHERE (value < 10000) 
AND (categories.kind = 'Attendance') 
AND (records.service_date_time >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000' 
AND records.service_date_time <= '2014-01-29 00:37:00.400862') 
GROUP BY to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
```

This returns all the proper data:

```
3036710 Aug 2013
2792991 Jul 2013
3344243 Jun 2013
3121535 Apr 2013
3752803 Sep 2013
2931149 May 2013
3046820 Nov 2013
4437698 Mar 2013
2709170 Jan 2014
3709154 Jan 2013
3361630 Dec 2013
3008767 Oct 2013
3474820 Feb 2013
```

However, I can't seem to order by the new date format column because it's a string. If I do so, it'll sort Apr 2013 first, then Aug 2013.  I need it sorted by month.  I've tried a few different things, like using to_date instead of to_char, and also trying to cast the column to a date before ordering.  No dice.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to do:

```
order by min(service_date_time)
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could add auxiliary column for sort:

```
SELECT SUM(round("records"."value")) AS sum_value, 
    to_char(service_date_time, 'Mon YYYY') AS to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy,
    max(to_char(service_date_time, 'yyyy-mm')) as yyyy_mm
FROM "records" 
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "records"."category_id" 
WHERE (value < 10000) 
AND (categories.kind = 'Attendance') 
AND (records.service_date_time >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000' 
AND records.service_date_time <= '2014-01-29 00:37:00.400862') 
GROUP BY to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
order by yyyy_mm
```

If you want to remove the auxiliary column, then:

```
SELECT sum_value, to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
FROM (... copy the above query here...) t
```

Comment: That's because there's `group by`. If there isn't `max`, the query will not run. You know that the value of `yyyy_mm` is the same within a single group, you can safely apply `max` function. This is common technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.sum_value, x.to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
FROM(
    SELECT SUM(round("records"."value")) AS sum_value, 
        to_char(service_date_time, 'Mon YYYY') AS to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy,
        to_char(service_date_time, 'Mon') AS month
    FROM "records" 
    INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "records"."category_id" 
    WHERE (value < 10000) 
    AND (categories.kind = 'Attendance') 
    AND (records.service_date_time >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000000' 
    AND records.service_date_time <= '2014-01-29 00:37:00.400862') 
    GROUP BY to_char_service_date_time_mon_yyyy
    ORDER BY month) x
```

The idea is to get another column with the month and sort by it, and you can do it in a subquery to avoid select the new column `month` on your result set.